# convert similar computed properties to use just one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have those 3 computed properties is it possible to make them in just one ?

```js
    first() {
      const mydate1 = new Date();
      mydate1.setDate(mydate1.getDate() + 1);
      return mydate1;
    },
    second() {
      const mydate2 = new Date();
      mydate2.setDate(mydate2.getDate() + 2);
      return mydate2;
    },
    third() {
      const mydate3 = new Date();
      mydate3.setDate(mydate3.getDate() + 3);
      return mydate3;
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean by "just one"? What is it exactly that you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly okay for a computed property...

```
dates() {
  const baseDate = new Date().getDate();

  const first = new Date();
  first.setDate(baseDate + 1);

  const second = new Date();
  second.setDate(baseDate + 2);

  const third = new Date();
  third.setDate(baseDate + 3);

  return { first, second, third };
},
```

Previous references to, say, `second`, can change to `dates.second`.  Same for all three.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using computed properties, why not make a method `getDate(offset)` that returns a new Date?

```
methods: {
  getDate(offset) {
    const myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + offset);
    return myDate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Something like you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7q9Ldhg/